# Exact Target JB4A-SDK with React Native, error while linking the lib

Tags: react-native

I've downloaded latest (no matter the version) version of JB4A SDK found here -> https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/JB4A-SDK-iOS

When I'm trying to link it with my React Native app (RN v0.45.1) I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNExactTarget.a(ETWKLandingPagePresenter.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRNExactTarget.a(ETInternalLandingPagePresenter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is to link the WebKit framework to the project.

Comment: Hey , Did you get the push notifications working with react native ?